# ExpressJS + Child process - Receive ajax request, process on child and send back response?

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 servers running 24/7 in a single process (file `server.js`):

- TCP Socket Server (from NodeJS's `net` module)
- `ExpressJS` HTTP Server

My TCP Socket Server receives messages from multiple gps trackers and inserts them on the DB (MySQL). It does that by instantiating a worker (a child process created by `.fork()` --> file `worker.js`) whenever it receives a socket connection; the worker will then take care of every following message coming by that socket.

My HTTP Server receives HTTP/AJAX requests from browser clients and answers them. Some of these requests require that my http server send the request to a worker so it can handle it better. The worker will then, later on, send back some information to the server.

Now, here it lies my problem. How can I send the response to the initial request from the browser? Should I just pass around the `(req,res)` objects from Express and when it comes back to the server, with the worker's information, I send whatever I want to the browser?

Comment: Do you mean sending req, res across some network connection and receiving them back? If so no... just post the data you need back and forth...

Comment: @DrewR Yes, I meant as a way of doing it. But the variable will be out of scope, I suppose. Supposing I have/will have the IP from the browser that made the initial ajax request, how can I send the information processed by the worker when the server receives it back? Is there anyway that I could "fake"/copy a `res.send()` ?

Comment: No.. you'll need to receive the response from the worker back into the express application and from there send it on to the browser as part of the response to the initial HTTP request.

Comment: @DrewR... How can I "receive the response from the worker back into the express application"? I know how to receive the response back from the worker, but how to get it back into the original request? Don't I need the request/response objects also?

Comment: Post the code where you receive the response from the worker and also your express handlers

Comment: Sorry for the lack of update, but I managed to eventually do it. In fact, it was pretty normal: I managed to store the response in an array of response objects and sent the message to the worker. The worker did his thing, returned the result and with that data I retrieve the corresponding response object from the array and use the response.send method (which still works, no matter how long it takes) to send the response back to the server. Should I answer my own question? By the way, I'm upvoting you for your help/effort.

Comment: @MagisterMundus Yes, you should answer your question.